# How can a pipeline or compound command be used with `:` and `echo`?

Tags: bash

> ```
> : [arguments]
> ```
>
> Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections.

How can a pipeline or a compound command be used with `:`?

Braces don't seem to solve the problem:

```
$ : { echo hello | cat; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
    
$ : { if test 1; then echo hello; fi; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Double quotes will prevent some expansions, which `:` allows.

The same problem happens when using `echo` instead of `:`.

```
$ echo { echo hello | cat; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
$ echo { if test 1; then echo hello; fi; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Basically I want to run a command up to expansions and redirections with `:`, and check the result with `echo`. The quote doesn't mention pipe and control flow keywords won't work, so I only expect that alias expansion will not happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Run that through `bash -vx script.sh` in order to see the misunderstanding. That is the useful way for handling `:` anyway: It (usually) does not harm the script run but you can see what's happening with `-x`. You cannot combine that with `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
: { echo hello | cat; }
```

The shell parses this command line. First it tries to find the end of the first command. That end is the pipe.

So the first command is

```
: { echo hello
```

which does nothing. Especially it pipes nothing into cat. With

```
: { echo hello | cat;
```

being gone there is only the `}` left which is not a valid command.

Comment: Thanks.  The quote doesn't mention pipe and control flow keywords won't work with `:`. But is it true that there is no way for them to work with `:`, or just I miss something?

Comment: @Tim You misunderstood my explanation. The control flow works exactly the same with `:` as with any other command. Maybe you want something like `{ : echo hello | : cat ; }`. In general `:` helps with the understanding of substitution only but not for commands.

Answer (score 2):

`:` is a command so it can be used in a pipeline just like anything else:

```
something | :
: | something
something | : | something-else
```

...but it won't do you any good since the `:` command does nothing: it accepts no input and produces no output. Therefore none of those are terribly useful pipelines (except I suppose the second one is a slightly shorter alternative to `something </dev/null`).

As for your sample commands:

```
$ : { echo hello | cat; }
```

This looks like a syntax error just as the shell reports it do be. The `{ ... }` construct can be used *in place of* a simple command, but not somehow... combined (?) with it. What exactly do you expect this compound command to do? Maybe you need to add more detail about what you are trying to achieve.